# How can i create vector image with jpg image with php imagefilter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, imagefilter

Please help me create vector image like this below, I tried to use image filter grayscale, however it is not creating the dark black I want, so if you can help me create dark black vector like this in PHP, that would be great.

This is the code below which I tried before, and it created a vector, but it was gray instead of black

from this image

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXg9F.jpg)

to  Image

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfqGf.png)

My code is

```
if($effect){

            imagefilter($dst_img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
             
            
           //imagefilter($dst_img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -100);
        }
```

My Full code is

```
    function createThumbnail($imageName,$newWidth,$newHeight,$effect)
    {
        $uploadDir="assets/front/collage/images/9fd0c8fe";
        $path = $uploadDir . '/' . $imageName;

        $mime = getimagesize($path);

        if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }

        $old_x = imageSX($src_img);
        $old_y = imageSY($src_img);

        if($old_x > $old_y)
        {
            $thumb_w    =   $newWidth;
            $thumb_h    =   $old_y/$old_x*$newWidth;
        }

        if($old_x < $old_y)
        {
            $thumb_w    =   $old_x/$old_y*$newHeight;
            $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
        }

        if($old_x == $old_y)
        {
            $thumb_w    =   $newWidth;
            $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
        }

        
        $dst_img        =   ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);

        imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);

        if($effect){

            imagefilter($dst_img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
             
            
           //imagefilter($dst_img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -100);
        }
        // New save location
        //$new_thumb_loc = $moveToDir . $imageName;

        if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $result = imagepng($dst_img); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img); }
        
        

        imagedestroy($dst_img);
        imagedestroy($src_img);
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php

createThumbnail('test.png',50,50,true);
function createThumbnail($imageName,$newWidth,$newHeight,$effect)
    {
        $uploadDir="assets/front/collage/images/9fd0c8fe";
        $path = $uploadDir . '/' . $imageName;

        $mime = getimagesize($path);

        if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }

        $old_x = imagesx($src_img);
        $old_y = imagesy($src_img);

        if($old_x > $old_y)
        {
            $thumb_w    =   $newWidth;
            $thumb_h    =   $old_y/$old_x*$newWidth;
        }

        if($old_x < $old_y)
        {
            $thumb_w    =   $old_x/$old_y*$newHeight;
            $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
        }

        if($old_x == $old_y)
        {
            $thumb_w    =   $newWidth;
            $thumb_h    =   $newHeight;
        }
        
        $dst_img        =   imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);
        
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);



        if($effect){

            imagefilter($dst_img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
            imagefilter($dst_img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -100);
             
        }
        // New save location
        //$new_thumb_loc = $moveToDir . $imageName;
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime['mime']); //Changed for my test
        if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $result = imagepng($dst_img); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img); }
            return $result;
    }
```

Comment: what did you changed?

Comment: Other than some formatting, this is all I added: header('Content-Type: ' . $mime['mime']); //Changed for my test

Comment: As you can see, this is what I'm already getting, but I want a dark, vector image like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfqGf.png instead of a grayscale image https://www.bestcheapcanvas.com/CollageTool/GetImage/9fd0c8fe/2305844108790452889_Pu002000023711.png

Comment: Updated answer. This is as close as I can get using a jpg image.  All I added is the IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST